# "this" in a swiper event is the Window, not the swiper

Tags: javascript, events, swiper.js

I have a simple page with multipe sliders. Each slider is comprised of three slides; left, middle and right. I want to reset all sliders to the middle if another one is changed. Think of this like a UI where you are swiping left or right to reveal actions that can be performed on an item in the list. I don't want multiple items to have their actions revealed at the same time - therefore swiping on one should reset all others back to their initial state.

The documentation says that in slider events that "this" will always refer to the slider in question, but for some reason it is referring to the Window and I can't figure out why.

Here is a simple example of this in action https://codepen.io/gurubob/pen/MWawvQK

```
$(() => {
    var swipers = [];

    function initSwiper(element) {
        var swiper = new Swiper(element, {
            // Optional parameters
            direction: 'horizontal',
            loop: false,
            initialSlide: 1,
            on: {
                slideChange: () => {
                    // The docs say that "this" is always the instance of
                    // the swiper in any events, but here "this" is the
                    // window and I can't spot why????
                    // Change all other swipers back to initial slide:
                    var thisSwiper = this;
                    swipers.forEach(swiper => {
                        if(swiper != thisSwiper) swiper.slideTo(1);
                    })
                }
            }
        })

        swipers.push(swiper);
    }

    $(function(){
        $('.swiper-container').each((idx, element) => {
            initSwiper(element);
        });
    })
})
```

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using an arrow function as the value of the `slideChange` property in the options passed to the Swiper.

Arrow function use the parent scope instead of having a new one: [Arrow functions MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

You can just use your `swiper` variable instead of using `this`:

```
slideChange: () => {
                    swipers.forEach(swiperItem => {
                        if(swiper != swiperItem) swiperItem.slideTo(1);
                    })
                }
```

Another option is to add the event listener separately:

```
var swiper = ...;
swiper.on('slideChange', () => ...)
```